# How to build Allure 2 report in java programmatically?

Tags: java, allure

I use own console runner based on Junit 5 to execute my tests. After getting test results I need to build report. I try to find any ways, but found solutions only for allure1. There is also a way to build a report from the command line using .bat file, but I would like to do without it.